# How does scala intersection & match elements in a set

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-2.9

I have two sets of objets and I want to get the intersection of the two sets. The objects in the sets look like this

```
@BeanInfo
class User {

  @JsonProperty
  @BeanProperty
  var name:String = ""

  @JsonProperty
  @BeanProperty
  var id:Long = 0

  override def toString = name

  override def equals(other: Any)= other match {
      case other:User => other.id == this.id
      case _ => false
   }

}
```

In another class I get the sets of users and want to see the intersection.

```
val myFriends = friendService.getFriends("me")
val friendsFriends = friendService.getFriends("otheruser")
println(myFriends & friendsFriends)
```

The above code does not work and prints

```
Set()
```

However if I manually loop over the sets using foreach I get the desired result

```
var matchedFriends:scala.collection.mutable.Set[User] = new HashSet[User]()    
myFriends.foreach(myFriend => {
  friendsFriends.foreach(myFriend => {
      if(myFriend == myFriend){
        matchedFriends.add(myFriend)
      }
  })
})
println(matchedFriends)
```

the above code prints

```
Set(Matt, Cass, Joe, Erin)
```

This works just fine

```
val set1 = Set(1, 2, 3, 4)
val set2 = Set(4,5,6,7,1)

println(set1 & set2)
```

The above prints

```
Set(1, 4)
```

Do the set operations & &- etc.. only work on primitive objects ? 
Do I have to do something additional to my user object for this to work ?

Comment: `myFriend == myFriend` really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% positive about this, but I think your issue is caused by having implemented a custom `equals` without a corresponding custom `hashCode`.  I'm sort of surprised your hash sets are working at all, actually...

Your manual loop through the elements of each set works fine, of course, because you don't call `hashCode` at all :)

Comment: added the  hash code and it worked thanks mergeconflict but not before working out a more scala version of the intersection which does not suffer from immutability if anyone is interested                           def has[A](set: Set[A], target: A): Boolean = {
   set.foldLeft(false){ (rv, item) => rv || target == item}
  }
  
  def union[A](set1: Set[A], set2: Set[A]): Set[A] = {
    set1.foldLeft(Set[A]()) { (union,item) => {
     if(has(set2, item)) union + item else union
      }
    }
  }

Answer (score 1):

From JavaDoc:

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method
>   whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general
>   contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must
>   have equal hash codes.

From ScalaDoc:

> Additionally, when overriding this method it is usually necessary to
>   override hashCode to ensure that objects which are "equal"
>   (o1.equals(o2) returns true) hash to the same Int.
>   (o1.hashCode.equals(o2.hashCode)).

`Set` is not working because you broke `hashCode` when you overrode `equals`.

Answer (score 0):

When overriding `equals` always override `hashCode` with it.